# What hardware issue is causing my packet loss? Is it fixable?

Tags: wireless-networking, hardware-failure, packet-loss

My laptop got a nasty bump today. A bit of the casing broke, and a corner of the laptop (including screen) is 'bent'.

Somewhat to my surprise, the laptop appears to be functioning close to normally: the only change I have noticed is that my wireless internet connection is working much less well. When pinging 8.8.8.8, I observe approximately 95% packet loss.

I have not yet been able to test how a wired internet connection is affected.

(While I am reasonably computer-savvy, I know essentially nothing about hardware.)

**Question**: What is (likely) causing this issue? Is the issue (likely) solvable or is the laptop essentially total loss, assuming that a good wireless network connection is important to me?

**Edit**: to my great surprise simply running `sudo service network-manager restart` in my terminal -- my go-to solution for *software* network problems -- appears to influence the situation. Immediately after running it, the network appears to be briefly stable (for up to maybe 20 seconds), after which it deteriorates again.

Comment: Have you checked to see if any components were knocked loose when it was bumped? Have you re-seated the wireless card? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Moses I haven't opened it up or taken it apart in any way. Unfortunately I don't have the tools to do that here (or at all -- would have to borrow them). I wouldn't know what a wireless card looks like (though I presume a google search would work?). I haven't done anything with the hardware except 'press the casing shut' as it appeared to be coming apart at one end and put some temporary tape on it to keep it together.

Comment: Probably the wireless antenna cable has been knocked loose. Go to your laptop manufacturer website and get a maintenance manual telling you how to get to your wireless card and reseat the antenna.

Comment: @Mokubai it appears that was exactly the problem. Thank you so much! If you would like to post your comment as an answer I'd be happy to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the Wifi is actually detected chances are the card itself is fine, but as Wifi is *almost* working probably the wireless antenna cable has been knocked loose.

Your laptop manufacturer should have a maintenance manual on their website telling you how to get to your wireless card to reseat the antenna.